# What is the difference between Java for loop vs Stream .forEach

Tags: java, lambda

The below for loop produces a collection of lambda expressions.

```
 Callable<String>[] tasks = new Callable[messageCount];
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   tasks[i] = () -> msg;
 }
```

Trying the same with stream forEach produces nulls.

```
 Arrays.stream(tasks).forEach(t -> {
   t = () -> message;
 });
```

What am i missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: Is `messageCount` and `count` supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stream code is equivalent to the following `for` loop:

```
for (Callable<String> t : tasks) {
    t = () -> message;
}
```

which itself is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    Callable<String> t = tasks[i];
    t = () -> msg;
}
```

Change the value of `t` does not change the value of `tasks[i]`.

To create an array of length `messageCount`, with elements being lambda expressions, use streaming:

```
Callable<String>[] tasks = IntStream.range(0, messageCount)
                                    .mapToObj(i -> (Callable<String>) () -> msg)
                                    .toArray(Callable[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first code sample, you are assigning the lambda expression `() -> msg` to each element of the `tasks` array.

However, in the second example, you are assigning the lambda expression `() -> msg` to a *temporary* variable `t` with type `Callable<String>`. The intention of [`Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) is to pass the elements of the stream to a *consumer* that uses the elements in some way. If you assign to the consumer's parameter in some way, the source of the stream will not reflect that. Such an operation might not even make any sense:

```
IntStream.range(1,10).filter((x) -> (x % 2 == 0)).forEach((x) -> {++x;});
```

This ties to a general theme of Java streams: they are unidirectional pipelines for producing, transforming, filtering, and consuming data. As data flows from the `Arrays.stream` supplier, it can only flow in one direction, into the consumer (`forEach`); changes made downstream will not propagate back upstream.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining the stream concept that I didnt fully understood earlier. This makes perfect sense.